# Browser.manage().addCookie() returns error missing 'name'

Tags: angularjs, cookies, protractor, automated-tests

When I am trying to set cookies in protractor, I am getting below error message:

> Failed: invalid argument: missing 'name' 
>   (Session info:chrome=61.0.3163.100)

[image]

I have used below different codes to set cookie in protractor. But none of them is working.

Case 1:

```
browser.get('http://localhost:8080');
browser.driver.manage().addCookie('test', 'test');
```

Case 2:

```
browser.get('http://localhost:8080');
protractor.browser.manage().addCookie({ 'name': 'test', 'value': 'test', 'path': '/', 'domain': 'localhost' });
```

Case 3:

```
browser.get('http://localhost:8080');
browser.manage().addCookie('test', 'test', '/', 'localhost');
```

I am running code with protractor version 5.2.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got solution of my problem. Below code worked for me.

```
(browser.manage() as any).addCookie({ name: 'test', value: 'test', domain: 'localhost' });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000');
browser.manage().addCookie('test', 'test', '/', '127.0.0.1');
```

Issue is with using localhost, use 127.0.0.1 instead

Please read further with issue with protractor [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/341)

Comment: Its not working gives same error. See I have attached image.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer using `browser.driver.get()` over `browser.get()`.

As far as `browser.driver.get()` returns a promise, you should take it into account:

```
browser.driver.get('http://' + domain + '/').then(() => {
  browser.manage().addCookie({name: 'foo', value: 'boo'});
});
```

Also notice, in this case you don't need to pass domain value to `addCookie` because protractor will use the current domain by default. This will also solve an issue with `localhost` which [Mohan Ram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217572/browser-manage-addcookie-returns-error-missing-name/47217690#47217690) mentioned